# Как убрать отсупы от transform: scale()

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка

Как убрать отступы от `transform: scale();`?

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.scale {
    background-color: green;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    transform: scale(.8);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="scale"></div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отправьте этот вопрос сюда: https://otvet.mail.ru/chiromancy/. Возможно там вам смогут помочь и без кода страницы.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vQYgqK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте свойство `transform-origin`:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.scale {
    background-color: green;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    transform: scale(.8);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="scale"></div>
```